# exception handling in c++ (in if statement)

Tags: c++, exception

I have a function takes integer array and integer as a parameter and find the integer in the array. if there is no such a integer  it throws ItemNotFoundException. My func works well but how can use this func in if statement. How can I can understand my func throw exception or not in if statement?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I can understand my func throw exception or not in if statement?

You basically can't. You can catch the exception and then handle the not-found case there but that's cumbersome. Your design could be improved if you did something other than throwing an exception. STL returns an end-iterator, as an example. If you're returning index of the element, you can return `-1` or size of the array for instance. The main problem is that you're using exceptions in a places they are not meant to be used.

My suggestion would be to use `std::find` and not invent the wheel anew.